# Convert a Spark's Data-frame's Json column as Object to Array of Object

Tags: json, dataframe, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I can read a json string in a dataframe that has one column "TEST" and one row.

As a result I have a dataframe with one column "TEST" where I have this value :

{
"TAXES": {
"TAX":
{
"TAXFREEFLAG": 0,
"TAXINCLUDEDFLAG": 1,
"TAXPERCENT": 5.5,
"TAXTYPE": 49,
"TICKETTAXABLEAMOUNT": 6.14,
"TICKETTAXAMOUNT": 0.34,
"TICKETTAXID": 1
}
}
}

How can I transform this column to have the following value ?
I want to transform a nested object into an array object.

```
{
    "TAXES": {
        "TAX": [
            {
                "TAXFREEFLAG": 0,
                "TAXINCLUDEDFLAG": 1,
                "TAXPERCENT": 5.5,
                "TAXTYPE": 49,
                "TICKETTAXABLEAMOUNT": 6.14,
                "TICKETTAXAMOUNT": 0.34,
                "TICKETTAXID": 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to break this down to 3 steps

Firstly you need to parse the original JSON string column to a struct using the `from_json` function.Then you need to reshape your struct to include the array.Finally you will need to convert the reshaped struct back to a JSON string using the `to_json` function.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import (
from_json, 
to_json, 
lit, 
struct, 
col, 
array)
from pyspark.sql.types import (
StructType,
StructField,
IntegerType,
DoubleType,
StringType,
)


## Initialize Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("JSON Transformation").getOrCreate()

# Sample data
data = [
    (
        """{ "TAXES": { "TAX": { "TAXFREEFLAG": 0, "TAXINCLUDEDFLAG": 1, "TAXPERCENT": 5.5, "TAXTYPE": 49, "TICKETTAXABLEAMOUNT": 6.14, "TICKETTAXAMOUNT": 0.34, "TICKETTAXID": 1 } } }""",
    )
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["TEST"])

# Define schema for parsing JSON
tax_schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("TAXFREEFLAG", IntegerType()),
        StructField("TAXINCLUDEDFLAG", IntegerType()),
        StructField("TAXPERCENT", DoubleType()),
        StructField("TAXTYPE", IntegerType()),
        StructField("TICKETTAXABLEAMOUNT", DoubleType()),
        StructField("TICKETTAXAMOUNT", DoubleType()),
        StructField("TICKETTAXID", IntegerType()),
    ]
)

taxes_schema = StructType([StructField("TAX", tax_schema)])

root_schema = StructType([StructField("TAXES", taxes_schema)])

# Parse JSON string to struct
df_parsed = df.withColumn("parsed", from_json("TEST", root_schema))

# Reshape struct to include array
df_transformed = df_parsed.withColumn(
    "reshaped", struct(struct(array("parsed.TAXES.TAX").alias("TAX")).alias("TAXES"))
)

# Convert reshaped struct back to JSON string
df_final = df_transformed.withColumn("TEST_transformed", to_json("reshaped"))

# Show result
df_final.select("TEST_transformed").show(truncate=False)
```